# EF 5.0 Code First mapping issues between 3 entities

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-relationship, entity-framework-5

I've got 2 entities:

```
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Seminar> Seminars { get; set; }
}

public class Seminar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<School> Schools { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; } // wrong??
}

public class Price
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }

    public virtual Seminar Seminar { get; set; }
}
```

How to map "Price" property for getting something like this:

```
var priceOfSomeSeminar = someSchool.Seminars[0].Price
```

Is it possible? So I think I need help with the Fluent API modelBuilder relationship establishment...

Answer (score 1):

Well, ICollection doesn't have an indexer, so you can't use array syntax with it.  You can, however, convert it to an IEnumerable and then convert that to a List, which can then be indexed.

But no, you are using the correct semantics, so this should just work.  No need to work with the fluent api.

I think you have an error though, Price should not have a School member.  There is no direct relationship between price and school.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I only need to return the value of "Price" for a "Seminar" with it's own property or method? Or I could map it with 'magic' of EF?

Comment: @skrkvv - I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm also not sure why your seminar has many prices.. Shouldn't the price be the same?  Or do you have different pricing structures?

Comment: Yes. Every School has an own pricing policy. For example, basic seminar in Moscow school costs 800$, but in Rostov the price for the same seminar is 450$...

Comment: @skrkvv - I see.  Then I would suggest a small naming change.  Price class should be SchoolSeminar, because it's actually a join object that contains a payload (price).  You would then not need the link between school and seminar, because SchoolSeminar is that link.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you help with the design of this class? Should it be in DbSet?

Comment: @skrkvv - All entities have to have a dbset